# Load objects in array and return array like result

Tags: dojo

I create in Dojo class element and classes in, out and motor which are derived from element. 
I load elements from JSON file and with dojo.foreach I create instance of given type. Is there in Dojo array for this ? How to add this to array ? ( I'm comming from Java and this is strange to me not to have types like List )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather unclear, but in JavaScript, arrays work like Java's arrays and arraylists.

```
var arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]; // array literal construction
var arr2 = [];

for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    arr2.push(i); // add new values to the array, like Java's Array#add()
}
// now arr2 contains the same values as arr1
```

For more info, see MDC's [`Array` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you've got [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) just like you do in Java, although their behaviour is quite different(see the link for more information). You can instantiate an array like this:

```
var data = [];
```

Or:

```
var data = [ 1, "hello", 23, 23.45 ];
```

As you can see arrays in javascript can contain mixed values.

Hope this helped.